# Can't commit changes to SQL Server Compact Edition database 

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a problem,

```
private void button_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      string connectionString = @"Data Source=Database_TouchPOS.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
      using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
      {
         using (SqlCeCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
         {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Product (Title,Price,Category_Id) VALUES (@title, @price,@category_Id)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", textBox_Title.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBox_Price.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_Id", comboBox_Category.SelectedIndex);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Product Added Successfully...");
         }
         connection.Close();
      }                
   }
   catch (SqlException ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Everything seem to be fine, but still can't add data into database.

1. I did try with complete database path, example `c:\project\database.sdf`
2. I did a lot of search before asking. I saw similar problems but not even a single one works for me.
3. Data are added when compiling but not committed to database. I can see the data after second attempt of debugging.
4. Please kindly try to explain in detail.

Thanks

Comment: using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))  con))

What is the con here ?

Comment: that will be a comment i deleted, fixed!, thanks

Comment: Where is your database file located? In the bin directory? Check that it is not overriden by the default file and try to place it somewhere else.

Comment: it is located in : C:\Users\PCName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project-1\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably facing this, http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/05/faq-why-does-my-changes-not-get-saved.html suggest you use a full path to your database file in your connection string.

Comment: already did,Source=|DataDirectory|\Database_TouchPOS.sdf;Persist Security Info=False; or Source=C:\Users\MMGamers-1\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TouchPOS\TouchPOSDatabase_TouchPOS.sdf;Persist Security Info=False; ... not working

Comment: it works really well with SQLExpress but I don't really want to do ,I just want to run the database on portable drive.BTW, I am using.net framework 4.

Comment: thanks @ErikEJ , actually VS create a folder "Bin\Debug" and mirror the database. If you connect with the database from "Bin\Debug" . It works. .Net is weird.Thanks everyone for your precious time. exampe .\Bin\Debug\MyDatabase.sdf .

Comment: complete example for those seeking like me... @"Data Source=C:\Users\MYPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProjectFolder\MyProject-1\bin\Debug\MyDatabase.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use transactions explicitly?

```
IDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
//add to database
transaction.Commit(); // before close connection
```

Comment: @lxti , I did try with what you suggested not working. Kind of file permission problem? I am using window 7, 32bit version with VS2010.

Comment: @Wayne Tun, Did I understand right, that data is stored in database, and you see it after second launching program?

Comment: yes @lxti exactly , but I can not see changes to table. If you close and start visual studio again, every data gone.

Comment: @Wayne Tun , You are able to see data for the first time in the table but when you restart your VS data is not in db is taht correct ?

Comment: May be its a kind of bug in SqlCeConnection. I have no any idea about SqlCeConnection. But is it possible to try OleDbConnection? See examples there: [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce)

Comment: @ShaliniPavan, I also have  DataGrid in another tab (i am using tab control) to  view result. Nothing was made to database.

Comment: @Wayne Tun , I am not sure you can use sqlce in windows7 and vs 2010 and why not you try  sqlconnection instead of sqlce

Comment: @Wayne Tun : Try setting the platform target to x86 and see

Comment: @ShaliniPavan , local database is fine , i don't want to run database server on client machine.

Comment: I am planning to put inside a memory stick and provide and .exe file that will read database from that memory stick. Portable version.

Comment: And again in your code you are using SqlException change it to SqlCeException()

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old thread, so I don't know if it will help anyone if I put my answer.

I had this problem, too. 
When I executed an update or insert code in C#, apparently, everything was ok, but when I looked up the database, there was no change.

The thing was that while debugging I had the database opened in a Management Studio. And somehow this obstructed the database changes even when there was no error message.
Closing the Management Studio and opening it after executing the code, the changes where perfectly stored in the data base.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

complete example for those seeking like me... `@"Data Source=C:\Users\MYPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProjectFolder\MyProject-1\bin\Debug\MyDatabase.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";`

thank for this example. This saved my day.